# RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm new to Machine learning and numpy and i have been trying to run gradient descent on Boston housing dataset from sklearn my implementation worked for small random dataset but in boston dataset it is producing these warnings

```
<string>:12: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
<string>:15: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
```

and then the output is

```
Output
array([ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,
    nan,  nan,  nan])
```

this is my code for gradient descent

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
def gradient_descent(x,y,alpha,theta):
    m=y.shape[0]
    xtranspose = x.transpose()
    i=0
    cost =488
    while cost>0.5:
        hyp = np.dot(x, theta)
        loss = hyp - y
        cost = np.sum(loss ** 2)/(2*m)
        plt.scatter(i,cost)
        gradient = np.dot(xtranspose, loss)/m
        theta = theta - alpha * gradient
        i=i+1
    plt.show()
    return theta


    dataset = load_boston()
    m,n = dataset['data'].shape
    x = np.ones((m,n+1))
    x[:,:-1] = dataset['data']
    y= dataset['target']
    alpha=0.005
    theta=np.ones(x.shape[1])
    theta = gradient_descent(x,y,alpha,theta)
```

Comment: Need a better initial guess I think.  `loss ** 2` is overflowing, and causing the follow-on problems.

Comment: I am having the exact same errors, any idea how to fix it???

Answer (score 1):

It is not unusual to see such overflow warnings when the inputs are integers. The first thing to try would be to cast them as a float. If loss is an array, you can use loss =np.array(loss, dtype=float). If loss is an integer, you can use loss = float(loss).